# Pandas - Apply convex combinations to rows with exact same categorical features

Tags: python, pandas

So I have 2 pandas dataframes with their `dtypes`. I want to be able to apply a convex combination (So given some values x1 and x2 a convex combination is one where L is in [0,1] and L*x1+(1-L)*x2) to the none categorical features between all rows that have the same categorical features **EXCEPT** itself. Also there shouldn't be any duplicates(i.e. one row convex combo'd with another row multiple times). So for example:

```
Is taco?  Count  
yes        2  
yes        5
yes        1
```

Where `Is taco?` is `dtype` `category` and `Count` is `dtype` `Int`. x1 and x2 can be a vector of numerical features, but in the above case it's just 2 different rows of `Count`. There is only one categorical feature above which is `Is taco?` and they're all the same so we do the convex combination between all rows. If L=0.5 it should return

```
idx Is taco?  Count  
0   yes        3.5  
1   yes        1.5
2   yes        3
```

`idx=0` was calculated by 1st and 2nd row. So 0.5 * 2 + 0.5 * 5 = 3.5. Then `idx=1` calculated by 1st and 3rd row so 0.5 * (1 + 2) = 1.5. So as you can see the non-categorical features are combined via a convex combination. How can I do this with Pandas?

Comment: 1- can you double check your calculations? 2- can you provide an example with 4 rows? 3- can you explicit the calculation as comment at least for one row of the expected output?

Comment: Its unclear how you are getting 3.5, 1.5 and 3... also its quite unclear what x1 and x2 are. Could you elaborate?

Comment: added more exposition

Comment: You did not address what would happen with 4 or more rows, nor how to know which value is x1 and x2 (this matters when L != 0.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

func = lambda x: np.sum(np.array(list(combinations(x, r=len(x)-1))) * 0.5, axis=1)

out = df.groupby('Is taco?')['Count'] \
        .apply(func).explode().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Is taco? Count
0      yes   3.5
1      yes   1.5
2      yes   3.0
```

Another example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Is taco?': ['no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes'],
                   'Count': [1, 3, 5, 3, 6, 9, 12]})
print(df)

# Output:
  Is taco?  Count
0       no      1
1       no      3
2       no      5
3      yes      3
4      yes      6
5      yes      9
6      yes     12
```

```
# After combinations
>>> out
  Is taco? Count
  Is taco? Count
0       no   2.0
1       no   3.0
2       no   4.0
3      yes   9.0
4      yes  10.5
5      yes  12.0
6      yes  13.5
```

Comment: can you do this with lambdas not equal to 0.5?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: In fact, I don't understand why 'not equal to 0.5'

Comment: lambda is a parameter it can be set to anything

Comment: is there a way to group by multiple features? It might include multiple categoricals.

Comment: Yes you can. Use `groupby({'feat1, 'feat2', ...])`